# Animate CompositeTransform as independent animation (EnableDependentAnimation == false)

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-phone

I used the following code in windows phone 7 to animate a `CompositeTransform`:

```
        var da = new DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames() ;
        _storyboard.Children.Add (da);
        _translateXKeyFrame = new EasingDoubleKeyFrame {...}
        da.KeyFrames.Add (_translateXKeyFrame);
        Storyboard.SetTarget (da, _transform);
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(da, "TranslateX");
```

to animate the property I used this code:

```
        _translateXKeyFrame.Value = value;
        _storyboard.Begin ();
```

This code unfortunately does not work for winrt (the animation doesn't run).

For winrt there is the concept of dependent and independent animations. If I set the `EnableDependentAnimation` flag, then the animation seems to run. The problem is, that the animation only runs after the user has finished interacting with the touchpanel.

I guess the reason for that is that the UI thread is blocked while the user is doing something, so the dependent animation won't run.

Why does the animation not work, when it is run as independent animation (ie. with `EnableDependentAnimation` set to false)?

Answer (score 1):

EnableDependentAnimation property need not set for animating translation values. WinRT always recommend to animate the values, which does not affect the layout so that the animation will not block UI thread. To animate properties like Height/Width, it is necessary to set the EnableDependentAnimation to true.

RenderTransform and projection values can be animate without setting this property.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/415721/Fast-and-Fluid-Animations-in-your-Windows-UI-App

Comment: thanks for the link, I had read it already. But as you can see my animation does not affect layout, but a Transformation.

Answer (score 1):

This code works.

```cs
image1.RenderTransform = new TranslateTransform(); 

animateY = new DoubleAnimation();
animateY.from=0;
animateY.To += 200;
animateY.Duration = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(400);

Storyboard.SetTarget(animateY, image1.RenderTransform);
Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(animateY, "TranslateTransform.Y");

_story.Children.Add(animateY);
```